# How to use multiprocess to update pandas.dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiprocess

The goal of the following code is to sort the `big_df` by timestamp and ordered by `userid`. Finally, I get the `selected_df`.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

def init_process():
    big_df = pd.Dataframe()
    big_df = ... # It contains four columns and many rows.
    big_df.columns = ['userid', 'itemid', 'ratings', 'timestamp']
    users_list = Counter(big_df['userid'])
    selected_df = pd.DataFrame() # it is an empty dataframe
    for uid in users_list:
        small_df = big_df [(big_df[0] == uid )]
        new_user_items_df = small_df.sort_values(by=['timestamp'])
        selected_df = selected_df.append(new_user_items_df, ignore_index=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_process()
```

But when the `big_df` is so large, sometimes 80G, it will take many days to process it. Therefore, I want to use multiprocess to make it parallel. Then, I have the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from multiprocessing import Pool

selected_df = pd.Dataframe()
big_df = pd.Dataframe()

def process_pd(uid):
    global selected_df
    small_df = big_df[(big_df[0] == uid)]
    new_user_items_df = small_df.sort_values(by=['timestamp'])
    selected_df = selected_df.append(new_user_items_df, ignore_index=True)
    
def init_process():
    global big_df
    big_df = ... # It contains four columns and many rows.
    big_df.columns = ['userid', 'itemid', 'ratings', 'timestamp']
    users_list = Counter(big_df['userid'])
    selected_df = pd.DataFrame() # it is an empty dataframe
    
    num_cpus = 5
    process_pool = Pool(processes=num_cpus)
    dfs = process_pool.map(process_pd, users_list)

    print(selected_df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_process()
```

The `selected_df` is empty. I think maybe it is because the multiple processes do not update the global dataframe `selected_df`. But I am new of pandas, could anyone tell me how to modify this code?

Thank you very much.

Comment: the variable `selected_ratings` is never assigned in your multi-process code

Comment: It is my fault. Now I have changed it. The ```selected_df``` is empty.